# GCP Enable autoscale after startup script finished

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create `autoscaler` for `instance group manager` within GCP.

My problems:

- Autoheal health check is tcp health check which verify if port `8443` Is opened
- GCE instance startup script is very long and may least in extreme situation `3h`

Is there anyway to change GCE instance state to `RUNNING` only when startup script is finished? Or another way to let autodial wait for startup script to finish before recreating instance?

Answer (score 0):

**Autoheal health check is tcp health check which verify if port 8443 Is opened**

Create a health check for autohealing that is more conservative than a [load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks#create_a_health_check) health check.

Create a health check that looks for a response on port 8843 and that can tolerate some failure before it marks VMs as UNHEALTHY and causes them to be recreated. In this example, a VM is marked as healthy if it returns successfully once. It is marked as unhealthy if it returns unsuccessfully 3 consecutive times.

a. In the Google Cloud Console, go to the Create a health check page.

b. Go to Create a health check

c. Give the health check a name, such as example-check.

d. For Protocol, make sure that TCP is selected.

e. For Port, enter 8843.

f. For Check interval, enter 5.

g. For Timeout, enter 5.

h. Set a Healthy threshold to determine how many consecutive successful health checks must be returned before an unhealthy VM is marked as healthy. Enter 1 for this example.

i. Set an Unhealthy threshold to determine how many consecutive unsuccessful health checks must returned before a healthy VM is marked as unhealthy. Enter 3 for this example.

j. Click Create to create the health check.

**Running Instances** 
To pause a Autoheal until the MIG is stable, use the wait-until command with the --stable flag.

For full details you can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/autohealing-instances-in-migs#checking-whether-vms-are-healthy)

For example:

> gcloud compute instance-groups managed wait-until instance-group-name 
> --stable 
> [--zone zone | --region region] 
> Waiting for group to become stable, current operations: deleting: 4 
> Waiting for group to become stable, current operations: deleting: 4 
> ...
> Group is stable

You can refer to this link on [Setting up a health check and an autohealing policy](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/autohealing-instances-in-migs#setting_up_an_autohealing_policy)